# jQuery/ajax current navigation state on-click

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm currently working on developing a website with a jquery/ajax script that dynamically pulls in content from another page with a fade effect upon clicking on the corresponding tab in the navigation. [Click here](http://steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/) to view the page and the effect (only the first two pages are up for now - Home, Experience RGW). Here's the tutorial I was following for the effect: [CSS Tricks: Dynamic Page / Replacing Content](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/). I was able to get the page transition effect working fine, but I've lost the ability to change the active state of my navigation. The css and html are correct; the problem lies in the jquery/ajax dynamic page transition.

I was using the following php script to find the name of the document and apply the class "on" if the name was true (aka - the page is active)...(it worked fine before this jquery/ajax page transition):

The following code is used to name the page:

```
<?php $thisPage="home"; ?>
```

This code finds the name and applies the "on" class:

```
<li<?php if ($thisPage=="home") 
    echo " class=\"on\""; ?> class="highlt">
    <a href="index.php" class="home"><span>Home</span></a>
</li>
```

This worked fine prior to the jQuery/ajax page transition, however, now that the navigation div is outside of the content that dynamically loads for each page, I don't know how to change the current navigation state. The content that dynamically changes is within the "ajax" div in the page (just FYI)... and you'll notice that the navigation ("nav") div is outside of that. That's the reason it's unchanged from page to page.

Another reason I think the php call doesn't work is because it's in the header of the page, and when you navigate to another page and content loads in (dynamically within the "ajax" div), it doesn't refresh the header content of the page. So, even if I use the code referenced above to name a certain page and trigger the change of class in the navigation, it won't ever see it, because the header content is still from the original "index.php". I hope this makes sense.

Is there a jQuery script that can be written and triggered on-click of the navigation tab to remove or add the class "on" (selected state)? I'm sure it can be done, but I'm a jQuery novice. I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the window.location attribute... `window.location += '#example'` You'll have to add a little bit of logic/regex to remove any existing hash before adding the new one, but that should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dangerous area you're getting into. If I understand you correctly, you want to do the global navigation in Facebook-style, where the site never reloads.

If so, the problem you've encountered now is just the tip of the iceberg. Browser history and bookmarks won't work as expected, and you probably will have to write fixes for different browsers.

To answer your question, you probably want to use URL hashtags (like index.php#page-contact) which loads contact.php in your ajax div and then adds the active css class to the contact tab. If you want a simulated browser history, you need to use this method.

If you don't care about usability, accessibility and other essential topics, you can just write a few lines of jQuery that adds the class to the clicked element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#menu li').click(function(){

    $('#menu li').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
});

});
```